# How do I get my network icon back?

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia

System specifics:
Dell Vostro 14
OS - Ubuntu Linux 18.04
Using NVIDIA binary driver-version 340.107 from nvidia-340

Where it all started was when I couldn't see my home WiFi on my list of visible networks, so:-

1. I decided something was wrong with my network adapter (as people say Dell drivers are incompatible with Linux) so I started a 'typing code I didn't fully understand on my shell' spree! 
   I wrote commands like 
   "`sudo ishw-businfo`" to probably locate and fix my network drivers.
2. The command that made my network icon on top right itself disappear is:-
   `Sudo apt-get purge -y hostpad && sudo apt-get purge -y network manager && sudo reboot`
3. Following this, my network icons completely disappeared along with my bluetooth icon to the point that I cant figure out a way to connect my laptop to an internet connection. I tried a LAN cable too.

If anyone can suggest an action to REVERSE the command I foolishly typed in Step 2, I'd be immensely grateful.

As i see no way outta this,
I'm thinking of backing up and reinstalling Linux on my PC.

Comment: any useful hints in this resource? http://ubuntuguide.net/fix-network-connection-icon-disappear-on-top-right-panel

Comment: Tried editing the system-settings.conf file and restarting nw service, but i get a warning 'Set document metadata failed..'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Network Manager to connect to internet. Follow these steps as you mentioned in your question that you have wired connection. Once you are connected with internet, install those packages that you removed from system mistakenly.

1. Open Terminal application (Try shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Type `ifconfig` and identify your wired interface (Assuming eth0 here).
3. Type `sudo dhclient eth0` to get dhcp IP from your router and get connected.
4. Type `ping google.com` to check your internet connection.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: As far as I understand the situation, I don't have any wired connection as of now. Eth0 does not appear to be my wired interface

Comment: eth0 was just an assumption. You can consider an interface starts with letter 'e'. If you don't have wired internet connection, try connecting your Android phone and enable USB tethering. After that you can find an interface starts with 'usb' in ifconfig command. Then follow the instructions that I added above with that interface.

Comment: Right. I forgot to mention that my bluetooth icon is blown too, right after my nw icon dissapeared. USB teethering didn't help

Comment: Check the status of bluetooth service: sudo systemctl status bluetooth

Comment: Don't really know what to make of it tbh, it says 'bluetooth.service;enabled;vector preset:enabled)' in the last line.